# Creating a login page on the role and administration basis

Tags: java, jsp, authentication, project, web-deployment

What is the way to make a login page in JSP for a college that will make the login on basis of department (CSE, ECE, mech) and administration role as (staff, hod, principal)?

Comment: It is impossible to know without more information. What kind of authentication and authorization models are being used? Any frameworks? Please provide more information about the problem, what you have tried, and exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

first of you create the database & create the table, in table one of the column name is usertype.

second one make JSP login page using bootstrap.

in login page when you tap on the submit button that time filter is call.
in filter you fired the SQL query.

in SQL query if user-type is principal then call the pricipal servlet, if user-type is HOD then call the HOD servlet.

last one in servlet we can use requestDispatcher to call the appropriate JSP page.

Comment: as i am a begineer to this platform. will you please send the source code to me at : ps92021@gmail.com